# How to show user online status on their posts?

Tags: theme-development, loop, wp-user-query

I've tried a lot to solve this but of no use. I have a classified wordpress website where users can post their ads. I want to show their online status on the ad they post (archive and single posts as well as user profile page)
I tried a code but it shows my own online status on each of the ads (not of the users).
Please help.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/374358/edit) to include the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Thank you for ur response but I've successfully implemented it 

Comment: You should still edit you question and add the relevant information and perhaps also add your solution, if not then I think you should remove this question, since it is no use to anyone in its current state.